# Unreachable unallocated space: resize & move partitions or fresh ubuntu install?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, gparted

I have a dual boot (Windows 7 + Ubuntu 18.04), with a data partition which is accessible for both OS.

I resized my windows partition and I want to allocate some of the free space to the Ubuntu OS and most to the data partition.

Unfortunately this will involve moving a lot of partitions since the unallocated space is located before my Ubuntu OS partitions; while the data partition is located at the end of the drive.

Please find a screenshot here: [Screenshot current setup partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo3Lv.jpg)

What would be the most safest procedure to divide the unallocated space among:

```
/dev/sda5;
/dev/sda6;
/dev/sda7;
```

and  most importantly,

```
/dev/sda4.
```

Please consider also that I do not have important files in the Ubuntu OS (sda5, sda6, sda7) --- although I do appreciate my customized settings.

Would it therefore be recommended to do a re-installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: First cancel pending operation.  Can try moving sda3 to the left, but sda2 is too full.  Should have more free space itself, but win 7 is also out of support now.

Comment: @user535733, thank you for the tip. However, I do not want to create an extra partition. I simply want to allocate more space to sda3 and sda4.

Comment: @crip659, thank you for the tips. Indeed the pending operation is a bit misleading. I just wanted to show that I have 200GB of free space in the middle. Win 7 doesn't have that so much space, but runs fine so far. I'm just using the data partition to store files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Windows 7 part...**

**Note**: Windows 7 is no longer supported

- /dev/sda2 is FULL!
- Boot into Windows 7
- Start the Disk Management utility
- Extend /dev/sda2 (C:) partition to give it more room

**The Ubuntu part...**

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- Backup your important Ubuntu files
- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **delete** partitions /dev/sda5/6/7 and /dev/sda3 (you won't be able to boot at this point)
- **resize** /dev/sda4 left side towards the left to the desired partition size
- click the Apply icon
- quit `gparted`
- start the `Ubuntu Installer` from the desktop
- do NOT manually partition the unallocated space, let Ubuntu do its own partitioning
- **reinstall** Ubuntu using the "along side Windows" option
- reboot into Ubuntu
- restore Ubuntu files from previous backup

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Kudos for putting so much time into it.

Comment: Many thanks for this useful answer. Deleting partitions /dev/sda5/6/7 and /dev/sda3 (you won't be able to boot at this point) seems indeed to be exactly the right idea. I'll do this later tonight. One follow up question, does the reinstallation allow to specify where to install it? If so, would you recommend to install it again between Win 7 & the data partition?

Comment: @sir_olf Yes, AFTER resizing sda2 and sda4, all of the unallocated space will be between them, and Ubuntu will install there when you choose to install "along side Windows" option. Don't manually setup partitions, your disk is too small.

Comment: @sir_olf status please...

Comment: @heynnema, my apologies for not providing an update yet. I had a few deadlines, so I postponed messing around with partitions until Friday. I'll give an update afterwards :)